# Expect an end but find on

Tags: applescript

I have a code like this

```
tell application "app"
    set 1 to something
    repeat with some in 1
        set refpdf to field "File Attachments" of record 1
        on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
        set refpdf1 to findAndReplaceInText(refpdf, "some", "some2")
        set libh to findAndReplaceInText(libraryname, "test", "test2")
        
    end repeat
end tell
```

It gives me an error, But I should change text with the on findAndReplaceInText command, what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues:

1. The handler must be on the top level of the script
2. `some` is a reserved word, use `something` else
3. A handler inside an application tell block must be called with `my`

---

```
tell application "app"
    set 1 to something
    repeat with somethingElse in 1
        set refpdf to field "File Attachments" of record 1
        set refpdf1 to my findAndReplaceInText(refpdf, "some", "some2")
        set libh to my findAndReplaceInText(libraryname, "test", "test2")
    end repeat
end tell

on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
```